# Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `'

Tags: color, titles, els-cas

I am getting this error which points to the input line where `\maketitle` is. The error goes away once I remove my `\title{}`. The code is down below:

Note: I am using overleaf.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}


\begin{document}

\title{title}                      
\tnotemark[1,2]

\begin{abstract}
abstract
\end{abstract}


\begin{keywords}
keyword
\end{keywords}


\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The errors are:

Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `'.

See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
...

l.31 \maketitle

Try typing    to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X   to quit.

main.tex, line 31
Package hyperref Warning: Ignoring empty anchor on input line 31.

main.tex, line 31
Overfull \hbox (123.62721pt too wide) detected at line 31

Comment: @Robo0110 Please provide a Minimal Working Example `` MWE` that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with \ `\end{document}, that compiles and shows the problem.

Comment: @Denis just did.

Comment: Using recent MikTeX installation on my PC I can't reproduce your problem.  You should contact Overleaf support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using `\title{mode=alt}` instead of just `\title`